# eclipse neon gcc c++ linker no libraries panel in ubuntu

Tags: c++, linker, eclipse-neon

I want to use eclipse c++ to program in OpenGL, normally I use visual studio in Windows, but Now I want to transfer to Ubuntu. Following some tutorial, I know I need to add some libraries, but I cannot find the GCC c++ linker libraries panel in eclipse neon, so strange, I can find it in indigo, which is the tutorial used. But in neon, I cannot find it. Some pictures are follow.
[eclipse indigo have libraries panel in GCC C++ linker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZxgA.png),
[eclipse neon have no libraries panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ocyV6.png).

------ added two hours later -----

I found the reason... Because I use Fatabulous as my system theme, it hides the panel because of the high contrast (I guess), and actually it is there. After switching to default Ambiance theme, I could see the panel.